# Could not load file or assembly DevComponents.DotNetBar2

Tags: dotnetbar

So I got this file which is supposed to convert an access database into SQL (for a specific program called PROFFIX, but that's not so important...). However, if I try to run it, it produces the following error:

```
Fehler beim Starten von PROFFIX dbConvert!
```

*(Error running PROFFIX dbConvert)*

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
'DevComponents.DotNetBar2, Version=10.3.0.4, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7eb7c3a35b91de04' or one of its dependencies. The located
assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'DevComponents.DotNetBar2, Version=10.3.0.4, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7eb7c3a35b91de04'
  at dbconvert.frmHaupt.InitializeComponent()
  at dbconvert.frmHaupt..ctor()
  at dbConvert.pxDbConvertFkt.Main()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

So anyone an idea what exactly is wrong with this DevComponents.DotNetBar2, and where I could find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The version of controls that your app is built with is not the same as version of controls shipped with the executable or DotNetBar was not included at all. You must always included with your executable exact same version of the DotNetBar your app was compiled with. .NET Framework always binds to exact version of assembly application is compiled with.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you already have its dll files, but you should install DotNetBar Module from http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/download.aspx

But current version is not 10.3.0.4.

You may find it through googling or require to them or me.